How to click on a "Data Only" tab using Selenium in Python?
I'm trying to automate interaction with a webpage using Selenium in Python. The page contains a tab bar, and I need to click on the "Data Only" tab. The element has the following HTML structure:
<div id="tabs" class="tabContainer2L">
  <div class="tab2L" id="_xdotabsregion2">
    <div class="tabDiv2L">
      <div class="tabDivA2L" id="_xdotabsregion3">
        <div class="tabStartSpace2L"></div>
        <div class="tabStartA2L"></div>
        <div class="masterTabBarTabSecondarySelected tabBGA2L">
          <a class="tabLink2LSelected" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Data Only">Data Only</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tabMiddleAN2L"></div>
        <div class="masterTabBarTabSecondaryEnabled tabBGN2L">
          <a class="tabLink2L" href="javascript:void(0)" title="PDF">PDF</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tabEndN2L"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

What I've Tried:
CSS Selector: I’ve tried to use CSS_SELECTOR to target the "Data Only" link:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('your-webpage-url')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
data_only_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[title="Data Only"].tabLink2LSelected')))
data_only_element.click()

driver.quit()

This doesn't seem to work, and the TimeoutException is thrown.
XPath: I also tried XPath:
data_only_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Data Only' and @class='tabLink2LSelected']")))
data_only_element.click()

But still, I’m facing issues with clicking the element.
Problem:

I’m encountering a TimeoutException, and the element isn't clickable. How can I make sure that I can click on the "Data Only" tab properly?
I suspect there might be other reasons the element isn't clickable, but I’m not sure if it’s related to page load timing, iframes, or other factors.
Environment:
Selenium 4.0
Python 3.x
Google Chrome
Could someone point out what I might be doing wrong and how I can click on the "Data Only" tab?


We're probably going to need the URL. The HTML looks simple enough. There could be more than one element that matches your locator, the element could be inside an IFRAME or shadow DOM, etc.

a.tabLink2LSelected[title="Data Only"] ?
